# Material-UI Grid how to apply to all the cells the same space, even if they are inside another container

Tags: flexbox, material-ui

I'm a beginner with CSS, material-UI and I'm trying to use the grid to have different panels on my page but all of them should have the same spacing between them. Also, I would like for them to look good when the page is been resized.

```js
    <Flex css={{ background: "purple", padding: "8px" }}>
      <Grid
        container
        justify={"space-between"}
        spacing={2}
        css={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      >
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
          <Paper css={{ height: "100%" }}>
            <Typography variant="h1">1</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper css={{ height: "100%" }}>
            <Typography variant="h1">2</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
          <Grid
            container
            css={{ height: "100%" }}
            spacing={2}
            justify={"space-between"}
          >
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={12} css={{ minHeight: "50%" }}>
              <Paper css={{ height: "100%" }}>
                <Typography variant="h1">3</Typography>
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={12} css={{ minHeight: "50%" }}>
              <Paper css={{ height: "100%" }}>
                <Typography variant="h1">4</Typography>
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper css={{ height: "100%" }}>
            <Typography variant="h1">5</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Flex>
```

[image: Edit Material UI Grid]

And this is how it looks the code so far. But the panels 3 and 4 are misaligned and the space at the bottom of the panel 4 is much bigger than the others. I don't know how to make it look properly, I have tried a lot of properties (`align-items`, `align-content`, `justify`, etc) without success

Full page

[image: Full page]

Reduced page

[image: Reduced page]